# Splitting a single column in r into 4 separate columns

Tags: r, regex, tidyr

I am in need of splitting a single data frame column (ID) into five separate columns (A, B, C, D, E). The columns need to be split by:

- A - First Letter
- B - All numbers until the second letter
- C - All letters until the last letter
- D - Last number
- E - Last letter

Heres an example:

Before

```
ID Conc
1 A01HGF1a  132
2 D02SDV2b  453
```

After

```
A B C D E Conc
1 A 01 HGF 1 a  132
2 D 02 SDV 2 b  453
```

I have attempted to use separate() from tidyr but cannot figure out how to utilize regex properly. Any help is much appreciated!

Here is what I have attempted thus far

```
`separate(df, ID, into = c("A", "B", "C", "D","E"), sep = "(^.)(\\d+)(\\S+)(\\d+)(\\S+)")`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `sub` here for a base R option:

```
df$A <- sub("^(\\w).*", "\\1", df$ID)
df$B <- sub("^\\w(\\d+).*", "\\1", df$ID)
df$C <- sub("^\\w\\d+(\\D+).*", "\\1", df$ID)
df$D <- sub(".*?(\\d+)\\D+$", "\\1", df$ID)
df$E <- sub(".*?(\\D+)$", "\\1", df$ID)
df

        ID Conc A  B   C D E
1 A01HGF1a  132 A 01 HGF 1 a
2 D02SDV2b  453 D 02 SDV 2 b
```

### Demo

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks! I'm new to regex and it's taking me longer than I expected to work through. I really appreciate it.